# Where to put Power BI sources to make report working properly?

Tags: powerbi

Im going to build PBI report. I already have SQL inquiry and a few excel files with relevant data. I need to put all of those sources together into one PBI lake. I'm wondering where should I put excel files - locally on my computer (my laptop works within company's netowrk) or somewhere on shared disc so that everyone could refresh this report on demand. I will be sometimes updating those excel files by inserting some data into them etc.

I need to avoid situation when user can't refresh report because doesn't have permission to the source - and by soource I mean excel sheet which theoretically would be on my work laptop. So, does putting excel files on shared disc solve the problem or not?

Need to mention that all users will be running the report locally on their laptops (but still within company's network)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using only PowerBi desktop? or are you also using PowerBI Service?

Comment: I build reports in PBI desktop. Need to ask IT if we have service as well. So if have service then what's the difference with regards to my question?

Comment: You will be able to use PowerBI service in the proper way only if all the users have a PowerBI pro license, or if the company has power bi premium. In case you are enabled to us PowerBI service, nothing will change for you, you can still use the network folder to store the data, but the IT will need to setup a PowerBI Gateway so powerbi service can access those data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution will be to create a network folder and grant the proper permissions to the users. (read-only for the common users, read-write for you, maybe ask for the creation of two AD groups to manage the permissions)

This way the data will always be available even when your laptop is off or out of the network.

The only moment in which you won't be able to edit the data is when a data load (made by a user) is in progress, but it shouldn't last long.

Comment: ok so if I understand you correctly network folder containing all source files would do the job. Thanks for clarification